# How can I draw a line between two points using the rgl package in R?

Tags: r, rgl

Whatever I try, the last call to `lines3d` does nothing and does not produce an error or warning message.

```r
library(MASS)
library(rgl)
set.seed(77)

## means
mu <- c(1, 3, 2)
## covariance matrix
Sigma <- matrix(c(3.0, 1.5, 1.0, 
                  1.5, 2.0, 0.5, 
                  1.0, 0.5, 1.0), 
                nrow = 3, byrow = TRUE)
## sample
d3 <- mvrnorm(n = 500, mu = mu, Sigma = Sigma)

from <- c(1, 3, 2)
to <- c(2, 2, 1)

par3d(windowRect = c(819, 88, 1492, 706))  
plot3d(d3[, 1], d3[, 2], d3[, 3], col = "blue", size = 5,
       xlab = "x", ylab = "y", zlab = "z",
       aspect = c(1, 1, 1))
points3d(from[1], from[2], from[3], col = "red", size = 10)
points3d(to[1], to[2], to[3], col = "red", size = 10)
lines3d(from, to, color = "red", size = 10)
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

Look at the help page `?lines3d`.   You need:

```
lines3d(c(from[1], to[1]),  c(from[2], to[2]), 
    c(from[3], to[3]), col="red", lwd=10)
```

Comment: Sorry, this is not working for me either ...

Comment: @UweM.:  that's not very informative.  What do you see?  I see a thin line.  To get a fat line, use `lwd = 10`, not `size = 10`.

Comment: Are you getting an error or no line or not the line that you want.

Comment: I just don't see a line, even with lwd=10, and I do not get any error message.

Comment: Hmm.  I am getting a line between the two points.   Have you tried rotating the picture a little?  You can grab it with your mouse and move around the viewing angle.

Comment: Yes, I did rotate it.